# select2 is not working when adding HTML code using jquery html() method

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 for search and select option. When I'm making that code added by jquery it's not working.I think `myselect` class is not calling.But in case of adding these same code normally(html,without using jquery) it's working fine.

output:-select2 working with normal HTML:
[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc5cO.png)

output:-select2, when jquery html() method is used:
[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH9nK.png)

```
$("#menu").html("<select class='myselect form-control' id='class-in-charge'  style=' width:100%;' ><option hidden selected disabled></option><option>Sahal EV</option><option>Muhammed Rahil</option><option>Venmuka Jishwanth</option><option>Freejin Ram Pacha</option></select>");
```

Can anyone help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: both approaches are valid so we need to see your actual code to help you

Comment: can u help me. I will send you my team viewer ID. can u check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to initialize the `select` after adding it to the DOM.

```js
let select = document.createElement('select')
select.className = 'myselect form-control'
select.id = 'class-in-charge'
select.innerHTML = '<option hidden selected disabled></option><option>Sahal EV</option><option>Muhammed Rahil</option><option>Venmuka Jishwanth</option><option>Freejin Ram Pacha</option>'

menu.appendChild(select)

$(select).select2()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Here's a jQuery only solution (though I prefer to not use jQuery if not necessary):

```js
$("#menu").html("<select class='myselect form-control' id='class-in-charge'><option hidden selected disabled></option><option>Sahal EV</option><option>Muhammed Rahil</option><option>Venmuka Jishwanth</option><option>Freejin Ram Pacha</option></select>");
$('#class-in-charge').select2()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Comment: There is a lot of code in that. For better understanding, I removed that remaining code inside the html() method. So I need to work with jquery only

Comment: Can u do one more favour

Comment: While clicking on select box Label is not being focused. I added form-control. But still its not working